# Annoying autoexpanding in Eclipse Java editor

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

Ladies and gentlemen,

writing Java code in the Java editor in Eclipse, I often encounter a very unpleasant and annoying behavior: folded blocks of code above or/and below the point I type in spontaneously and unexpectedly expand; sometimes a fragment of text around the input point collapses as if it was a block like a class body or a method, though actually it is not; sometimes the text gets scrolled up or down or the scope changes otherwise, and I lose the point where I was typing in; sometimes the cursor jumps to another point, and if I type on, I get something like

```
private Arra
public void foobar() {
}yList someMethod()...
```

Sometimes the text structure gets totally misinterpreted with the folding manager, and the only way to deal with it I've found is to restart Eclipse.

What is the reason of such a behavior and how can I get rid of it?

Eclipse Lina (4.4.2), Windows 2003 server x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to tell what is causing this, but I'd start by downloading a new fresh Eclipse and start a new workspace. This is not proper behaviour. Perhaps you have installed a plugin that behaves erratically or are running something more than eclipse that can cause issues.

Comment: Thanks! I'm relatively new in Eclipse and I thought it might be a known bug or feature, relating to a certain plugin or preferences configured for the editor. I'll try a new Eclipse a little later, after I finish an urgent piece of work.